# Finding the maximum value of the sum of the product of sets of 3 variables given their sum

Tags: inequality, optimization

Given $x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{2014}=2014$, what is the maximum value of: $x_{1}.x_{2}.x_{3}+x_{2}.x_{3}.x_{4}+x_{3}.x_{4}.x_{5}+...+x_{2012}.x_{2013}.x_{2014}$.

It looks like an application of AM-GM inequality on terms obtained after proper rearranging of the given objective function or restriction, but do not find clear what such rearrangement could be.

Comment: If $x_n$ can be less than $0.$ I don't see that it is bounded.

Comment: $x_{n}$ are greater or equal to zero .. sorry

Comment: My hunch is that it is $(2014/3, 2014/3,2014/3, 0,0,0,0\cdots 0)$

Comment: Mixing variables (www.normalesup.org/~kortchem/olympiades/Cours/Inegalites/Inequalities.pdf) is a standard technique for dealing with such kind of cyclic (or almost cyclic) but asymmetric problems. The key idea is simple: to assume that the involved max/min is achieved at some point of the form $(a,b,b,b,\ldots,b,b,b,c)$, then prove it through perturbations of a small set of variables.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\text{Objective} &= x_{1}.x_{2}.x_{3} + x_{2}.x_{3}.x_{4}+x_{3}.x_{4}.x_{5}+...+x_{2012}.x_{2013}.x_{2014} \\
&\leqslant (x_1 + x_4 + \dots+x_{2014})(x_2 + x_5 + \dots+x_{2012})(x_3 + x_6 + \dots+x_{2013}) \\
&\leqslant \left(\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_{2014}}{3} \right)^3  =\left( \frac{2014}3 \right)^3
\end{align}$$

However this bound is achieved for e.g. when $x_4 = x_5 = x_6 = \frac{2014}3$ and all other $x_i$ are zero, hence this is the maximum.